# How do I use the file provisioner with google_compute_instance_template?

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, terraform

Using Terraform, I need to copy files to Google Compute Engine instance templates. For this I normally use the [file provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html), but it doesn't work since it depends on [SSH connections](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html), which fail due to requiring externally accessible host addresses. Due to the dynamic nature of instance templates, I don't know how to assign externally accessible host addresses to instances.

How can I implement copying of files to GCE instances created through instance templates (via Terraform)?

### Example Terraform google_compute_instance_template Definition

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "node" {
  name = "kubernetes-node-template"
  machine_type = "g1-small"
  can_ip_forward = true
  tags = ["staging", "node"]

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source = "worker/assets/kubelet.service"
    destination = "/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service"
  }

  connection {
    user = "core"
    type = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I was about to add the exact same issue. I have almost identical configuration and it doesn't cause an error, but doesn't transfer the file. Are you receiving any errors on this attempt?

Comment: @Adron As I recall it fails to acquire an SSH connection with a visible error, yeah.

Comment: Ah, I was able to get the connection (at least no errors appear) to work but it doesn't actually transfer the file(s) that I set for source.

I did have to setup the gcloud ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine key (use gcloud init to set it up and try to make your first connection, then it will require you to setup the ssh key according to how the cli needs the key.) Once I setup the gcloud key and added that to the connection private_key value the error went away, so I assume it connected. My problem now is that there just isn't any file copy actually happening.

Comment: @Adron For me it fails with this error: `* dial tcp :22: getsockopt: connection refused`.

Comment: Ah, that should be resolved if you setup the Google Cloud gcloud cli and initiate the ssh key creation from it. I'd be surprised however if your file actually copied.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: It's my understanding that instance templates can't actually be connected to or provisioned with files or scripts as they are not running machines, only templates. Probably best to build an image with the files or provision them one the instances boot up from the template

Answer (score 7):

I was able to resolve this issue with the following configuration.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "hubmud" {
    name = "hubmud"
    machine_type = "f1-micro"

    tags = ["buildserver", "jenkins", "central", "terraformer"]
    tags = [ "http-server" ]

    zone = "us-central1-b"

    disk {
        image = "ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20160406"
    }

    network_interface {
        network = "default"
        access_config {}
    }

    provisioner "file" {
        source = "installations.sh"
        destination = "installations.sh"
        connection {
            type = "ssh"
            user = "ubuntu"
            private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/google_compute_engine")}"
        }
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "chmod +x ~/installations.sh",
          "cd ~",
          "./installations.sh"
        ]
        connection {
            type = "ssh"
            user = "ubuntu"
            private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/google_compute_engine")}"
        }

    }

    service_account {
        scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
    }
}
```

The SSH key I used was the one generated by the gcloud instance, and the file to copy has to be in the format as shown. I did run into problems with using `~/` or just `./` to designate where the file is. It's also important to note that the file copied under the "ubuntu" account, which appears to be a default account on ubuntu that GCE has on the image by default.

Just to note, I also added the `type = "ssh"` even though that is the default for the connection type, so it isn't needed. I like to be verbose with some things in my configuration files though, so I added it.

Comment: I think a key part of this question is that the author is looking to provision an instance template, not a plain instance. This difference should be clearly noted in your solution

Comment: The `connection {` closure including the type, user and private_key solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can SSH into **google_compute_instance**s (this is a concrete, tangible VM afterall), but not into neither a **google_compute_instance_group_manager** nor into a **google_compute_instance_template** as these are abstractions.

as stated in here https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/52, this is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this feature was added later, but as of early 2021 you can use the optional [metadata_startup_script](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template#metadata_startup_script) argument of the [google_compute_instance_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_template) to specify a script that will run each time any instance created from the template starts up:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "hubmud" {
    name = "hubmud"
    machine_type = "f1-micro"

    tags = ["buildserver", "jenkins", "central", "terraformer"]
    tags = [ "http-server" ]

    zone = "us-central1-b"

    disk {
        image = "ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20160406"
    }

    network_interface {
        network = "default"
        access_config {}
    }

    # As per the documentation for google_compute_instance_template (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_instance_template#metadata_startup_script)
    # you can set either metadata.startup-script or metadata_startup_script
    # to the contents of a file that will be added to the metadata of
    # any instance created from the template. 
    # In both cases the script will run each time the instance starts. 
    # The difference is that if metadata_startup_script is used and the metadata 
    # value is changed the instance will be destroyed and recreated before 
    # running the new script.
    metadata_startup_script = file("${path.module}/installations.sh")

    service_account {
        scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
    }
}
```

Note that this mechanism requires OS support, but as [the documentation for the underlying arguments on google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#metadata_startup_script) points out:

"Most linux-based images will run the content of metadata.startup-script in a shell on every boot. At a minimum, Debian, CentOS, RHEL, SLES, Container-Optimized OS, and Ubuntu images support this key. Windows instances require other keys depending on the format of the script and the time you would like it to run."

Tested as far back as Ubuntu 16.04, which reaches EOL for LTS at the end of this month. So this feature has been around for 5+ years. Not clear if it was exposed by the GCP Terraform provider that long ago, but it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

When you up first your instance you can use metadata for the run script and whatever do but it works only once. For a replay, metadata need to recreate the instance.

```
metadata = {
    startup-script = "echo LOL SSH CONNECTION > /test.info"
}

OR

metadata = {
    startup-script = "${file("${path.module}/shared/runner/bootstrap.sh")}"
}
```